# How to resolve my smoothPage indicator change list of card with carousel slider image change?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am a fresher to flutter. I change or scroll my 1st card carousel slider image scroll, at the same time below card smooth page indicator change as per 1st card.
When I scroll the carousel slider change and smooth indicator, all the list of the card change. I want only the current card indicator to change, and other card indicators to not change.

```
int _current =0;

final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

 alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                    // onDotClicked: (index){
                    //   _controller.animateToPage(index,
                    //     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                    //     curve: Curves.ease,);
                    // },
                    activeIndex: _current,
                    count: 3,
                     effect: JumpingDotEffect(
                        dotHeight: 10.h,
                        dotWidth: 10.h,
                        jumpScale: .7,
                        verticalOffset: 20,
                        activeDotColor: Colors.red,
                        dotColor: Colors.grey),
                  ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Carousel Options here is onPageChange you can pass the setState inside in the onPageChange this will update the ***_current*** variable in the BuildContext that we are using the ***_current*** variable inside in AnimatedSmoothIndicator on *activeIndex* this will change the animatedSmoothIndicator position.
**Read the code Or copy and paste the code for better understanding.**

```
Column(
    children: [
      CarouselSlider(
          items: const <Widget>[
            Card(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('CarouselSlider Page 1'),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('CarouselSlider Page 2'),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('CarouselSlider Page 3'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          options: CarouselOptions(
            height: 200,
            initialPage: 0,
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 3),
            autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
            autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
              setState(() {
                _current = index;
              });
            },
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          )),
      AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
        activeIndex: _current,
        count: 3,
        effect: const JumpingDotEffect(
            dotHeight: 10,
            dotWidth: 10,
            jumpScale: .7,
            verticalOffset: 20,
            activeDotColor: Colors.red,
            dotColor: Colors.grey),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Thanking you .Abdullah brother